# Counting pairs column elements with the same value in a data frame and shows in a matrix format

Tags: r, cross-product

I was searching on internet for similar solution, but I was not able to find the specific one for my case. Let's say a have the following data frame:

```
a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
b = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
c = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
d = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)
```

and `df` looks like this:

```
  a b c d
1 1 2 2 1
2 1 1 2 2
3 1 1 1 2
4 2 1 1 1
5 2 2 1 1
```

**Note:** In this example I use `[1,2]` pair of values, but it could be a set of different values: `[-1,1]` or even more than two possible values: `[-1,1,2]`.

Now I would like to have a matrix where each `[i,j]` element will represent the number of rows with the value `1` for column `i` and `j`. For this particular case we have (showing the upper diagonal, because its symmetric):

```
  a b c d
a 3 2 1 1
b   3 2 1
c     3 2
d       3
```

The diagonal should count the number of rows with `1` value at a given column. On this case all columns have the sames number of value `1`. The format should be similar to `cor()` function (Correlation Matrix).

I was trying to use `table()` (and also `crosstab` from `descr` package) but it shows the information by pairs of columns.

It can be done by computing manually  the occurrence of `1` of each pair of columns (i.e.: `nrow(df[df$a==1 & df$b==1,])=2`) and then putting into a matrix, but I was wondering if there is a built-in function that simplify the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `crossprod` on a `matrix` for computing the occurrences of the value `1` of the question´s example:

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df == 1) # see Note[1]
out <- crossprod(m1)
```

**Note[1]** Pointed by @imo (see comments below) for addressing the general case   (a matrix with values: `[x,y]`). For a matrix with `[0,1]` values  `df==1`can be replaced by `df`. For counting the `2` values from question's example, then use: `df == 2`.

If the lower diagonal should be `0` or `NA`

```
out[lower.tri(out)] <- NA
out
#   a  b  c d
#a  3  2  1 1
#b NA  3  2 1
#c NA NA  3 2
#d NA NA NA 3
```

Comment: `crossprod(m1)` Nice solution

Comment: @Onyambu thanks you are right.  I didn't check the arguments

Comment: @akrun, it works because my example uses `[0,1]` values, but I would like to  count the frequency mainly. For example for other pair of values `[-1,1]` it would not get the expected result unless making a transformation first. It could even apply for factor data type.

Comment: @DavidLeal  It would have been better if the example included a general case instead of just 0 and 1

Comment: @akrun I changed `0` values with 2 and added a Note specifying that it could be other possible values. Your solution is very elegant, but it just applies for the `[0,1]` case. The question was generic, but then the example too specific.

Comment: @DavidLeal To get this solution to work for your more general case, replace df with `df == 1`. Also, changing the question after someone has answered is discouraged.

Comment: @Imo, just to clarify, I didn't change the question (it says from the beginning "counting" it does not imply necessary a mathematical operation), it is accurate from the beginning, just the example was a particular case. Sorry

Comment: @DavidLeal as @lmo suggested the `crossprod(df == 1)` should give the expected